# Print one list of email id's from a input of 2 lists using html-javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pretty much new to javascript. Here's my code for taking multiple email id's as input for 2 lists and getting the second list of email id's as output on the same webpage as of the inputs taken.

```
<form action="accept.php" method="POST">
    List1: <input type="email" id="myEmail" name="usremail" multiple>
    List2: <input type="email" id="myEmailTwo" name="usrtwoemail" multiple>
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="print"></p>

<script>

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("myEmail").multiple=true;
    document.getElementById("myEmailTwo").multiple=true;

    var x = document.getElementById("myEmailTwo").elements;

    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML=x;

</script>
```

I have no idea what's going wrong but the output says 'undefined'. Can anyone just guide me for getting the exact output. Thank You in advance!

Comment: I dont know what you want here. Is it a multi selection list?

Comment: @srk your javascript function "myfunction()" has not been closed. Please close it.

Comment: @Krishnakumar_Muraleedharan : I have taken the email id's in each of the lists - list1 and list2 which will be user inputs. I want the list 2 to be given as output on the same webpage as of the input webpage.

Comment: @Srk The HTML control you are using is not suitable for list. It is just a text box specialised for email. Try this instead 
    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myEmailTwo").value;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are trying to do but, replace this

```
var x = document.getElementById("myEmailTwo").elements;
```

by

```
var x = document.getElementById("myEmailTwo").value;
```

You are getting an `undefined` because there is no `elements` attribute to the `input` you are getting with `document.getElementById("myEmailTwo")`.

```html
<form action="accept.php" method="POST">
    List1: <input type="email" id="myEmail" name="usremail" multiple>
    List2: <input type="email" id="myEmailTwo" name="usrtwoemail" multiple>
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="print"></p>

<script>

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("myEmail").multiple=true;
    document.getElementById("myEmailTwo").multiple=true;

    var x = document.getElementById("myEmailTwo").value;

    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Even after using the '.value' stream, it won't print anything. Would there be any other way?

Comment: I have edited and added a Code snippet showing that it's working. If it still not working the way you want, maybe you should explain a bit more what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you getting a single list of email Id's that is the same input you have put in the List2 id ("myEmailTwo"), the same thing on the webpage?

Comment: I'm geeting exactly what I have written in the input `<input type="email" id="myEmailTwo" name="usrtwoemail" multiple>`, yes.

Comment: Okay! It definately isn't working for me. Something must be wrong with my computer. In anyways I feel the answer you have posted is a very correct one so I will mark it correct. And also, I appreciate your effort, Thank you very much!

Comment: Which browser are you using ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142276/discussion-between-maincore-and-srk).

Comment: I am using Google Chrome browser and Wamp server

Answer (score 0):

If you want use jquery, and want to apply values to `#print` container:

```js
function myFunction() {
  $('#print').text($('#myEmail').val() + "\n" + $('#myEmailTwo').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="accept.php" method="POST">
    List1: <input type="email" id="myEmail" name="usremail" multiple>
    List2: <input type="email" id="myEmailTwo" name="usrtwoemail" multiple>
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="print"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace you function with following,

```
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("myEmail").multiple=true;
document.getElementById("myEmailTwo").multiple=true;
var emails = []
var ids = ['myEmail','myEmailTwo']
for (var i =0; i < ids.length;i++){
    emails.push(document.getElementById(ids[i]).value)
   }

document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = emails;
}
```

Comment: It still won't print the email Id's. Yes I thought of using this and the for loop as well. But it won't work.